# Update the progress of a ProgressBar while using a Service?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-progressbar

I am trying to update a progress bar while downloading a file, but in my Service task I do not have any access to the UI. This means I cannot find the ProgressBar element using findViewByID in order to update the ProgressBar. Here is the relevant code:

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startService(View view) {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }
    public void stopService(View view) {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }
}
```

MyService Class:

```
package com.example.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyService extends Service {
    int counter = 0;
    static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        doSomethingRepeatedly();


        try {
            new DoBackgroundTask().execute(
                    new URL("http://www.amazon.com/somefiles.pdf"),
                    new URL("http://www.wrox.com/somefiles.pdf"),
                    new URL("http://www.google.com/somefiles.pdf"),
                    new URL("http://www.learn2develop.net/somefiles.pdf"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (timer != null){
            timer.cancel();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void doSomethingRepeatedly() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("MyService", String.valueOf(++counter));

            }
        }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    }

    private class DoBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            int count = urls.length;
            long totalBytesDownloaded = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                totalBytesDownloaded += DownloadFile(urls[i]);
                publishProgress((int) (((i + 1) / (float) count) * 100));
            }
            return totalBytesDownloaded;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            Log.d("Downloading files", String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "% downloaded");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "% downloaded-"+counter,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Downloaded " + result + " bytes",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //stopSelf();
        }
    }

    private int DownloadFile(URL url) {
        try {
            //---simulate taking some time to download a file---
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //---return an arbitrary number representing
        // the size of the file downloaded---
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to update the ProgressBar in my MainActivity by using the bytesDownloaded variable in my MyService class, but I'm not sure how to handle the Async call in my MainActivity. If that is even possible.

Thanks!